# x264 to convert odd-sized image sequence

Tags: video, images, x264

I've been using this command to convert series of JPEG images to h264 encoded videos, and it's been working quite well.

```
x264 "/path/to/input/%04d.jpg" --crf 18 -o /my/output/file.mp4
```

until recently I tried to run it on a series of JPEG images that *happen* to have odd dimensions (in my case, 437x437).  Now I get this output:

```
ffms [error]: could not create index
lavf [info]: 437x437p 1:1 @ 25/1 fps (vfr)
resize [error]: resolution 437x437 is not compliant with colorspace i420
```

I could swear that I've run across this error before and that the solution was to add a crop filter to the command

```
--vf crop:0,0,1,1
```

so that the video will be cropped to a compatible size before attempting to encode, but now when I try it this seems to make NO difference.  I can even put in outlandish values for the crop parameters, and it doesn't complain at all, which suggests to me that x264 is trying to resize the input somehow before it processes my crop filter, and so it errors out before I get the chance to fix things.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

In case it makes any difference, this is on Ubuntu 12.04, with x264 from the system 'x264' package.

Comment: This is weird because the check should be made after setting the desired width: https://github.com/DarkShikari/x264-devel/blob/master/filters/video/resize.c#L477

Comment: @slhck seems like the problem is that it starts with a generic call to the [resize filter](http://git.videolan.org/?p=x264.git;a=blob;f=x264.c;h=df18a1b1425f77fd420a23c7356d91187059743a;hb=HEAD#l1165) before it does anything user specified, and that first call is what fails.

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug to me, or even s regression?

Comment: did you get an answer for this?

Comment: @Prof I gave up on getting the filter to work.  I got the encode to run by cropping the first frame with imagemagick (only need to crop the first frame).